# AAVE Protocol v1 issue on reserve addresses with compound ctoken addresses

Tags: kovan, defi, aave, compound-protocol

https://kovan.etherscan.io/tx/0xa7f5e857d1a9ecb4aca0714b24a70ca0942cc1a656c8e09b6d01bab9af4ec9e5

I am trying to make a transaction from DSProxy (Smart Wallet) on a contract
https://kovan.etherscan.io/address/0x718099d292b1ad14555e25889a91e7d11552ec0c#code

Which make a importLoan transaction on the aave protocol v1 address of lending pool
the token are of compound protocol , which needs to get loan on a contract which is :
https://kovan.etherscan.io/address/0x847c2772610712407f9afd780cdb206658913944

In this case what i see, on kovan the transaction is failing because the reserve address of ctoken is not avalible on aave protocol , if yes let me know how i can run this on kovan network !?